# Limits and L'Hopital

Tags: complex-numbers, limits-without-lhopital

$$\lim_{z \to i} \frac{z^4-1}{z-i}$$

I'm reading in a bunch of places that I can't use L'Hopital's rule for this problem. Why is this so? And if I can't use this rule then how would I go about solving this? Using the rule resulted in $\lim = -i$

Comment: How did you get $-i$ using L'Hopital's rule?

Comment: Can you provide a link that says so ?

Comment: To be clear, I see no problem applying L'Hopital's rule here.  Both numerator and denominator are analytic near $i$...but differentiating the numerator gives $4z^3$ and differentiating the denominator just gives $1$ so application of the rule gives $4i^3=-4i$ (same as you get from the straight forward division).

Comment: @Yves Daoust: Baby Rudin (1976 3rd edition, Example 5.18, pp. 112-113) gives the example $f(x)=x$ and $g(x)=x+x^{2}\exp(ix^{-2}),$ where $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0^{+}}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = 1$ and $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0^{+}}\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)} = 0.$ A similar example is given in Jeffrey Dennis Weston, *A remark about l'Hospital's rule*, **Mathematical Gazette** 44 #348 (May 1960), pp. 126-127.

Comment: Finally, four different additional hypotheses under which L'Hopital's rule holds for complex-valued functions are given in D. S. Carter, *L'Hospital's rule for complex-valued functions*, **American Mathematical Monthly** 65 #4 (April 1958), pp. 264-266.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro: I am not sure that the two problems are equivalent. The cited references are about complex functions of a real variable, while yours is a complex function of a complex variable. These aren't equivalent as the limit of a complex variable involves more "directions".

Comment: @Yves Daoust: Yes, this does seem to be a different context, which I missed in my hurry to get this transferred from some personal notes (I'm at work). However, in thinking about things now, it seems that if anything, the example is actually stronger than what's needed, since we can interpret these as functions of a complex variable and consider the failure to be stronger than what we needed, since the failure occurs even when the limit is restricted to an approach along the positive real axis. (Although I guess we'd then need the "differentiated limit" to exist for any approach . . .)

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro: could very well be that in the complex none of the limits exists.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

$$z^4-1=(z^2-1)(z^2+1)=(z+1)(z-1)(z+i)(z-i)$$